# How do I get the motherboard temperature?

Tags: cpu, temperature, motherboard

I was able to get CPU temperature with lm-sensors.

But I don't know how should I get the motherboard temperature.

Comment: Same way -- lm-sensors has all temps. Your motherboard's temp will vary from location to location, so it's not clear what you are looking for.

Comment: If you run `sudo sensors-detect` you can see if it supports your motherboard chipsets to pull the temps.  Note that not all motherboards are supported.